# Using yield from to refactor a factorial implementation, yielded unexpected results

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, factorial, python-3.8

The first function below, implements a recursive version of a factorial function using the `yield` statement.

I was trying to apply the `yield from` statement in this `factorial()` in order to experiment and learn with it.
So, I wrote the `factorial2()` function, which despite printing the correct factorial, it didn't print  all previous values like `factorial()`.

I was wondering if there is any way to get the exact same functionality as `factorial()` in `factorial2()`?

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        yield 1
    else:
        for u in factorial(n - 1):
            yield u
        yield u * n

def factorial2(n):
    if n == 1:
        yield 1
    else:
        yield from (i * n for i in factorial2(n - 1))

def main():
    for u in factorial(12):
        print(u)
    for a in factorial2(12):
        print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Output:

```
1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
3628800
39916800
479001600
479001600
```

Expected Output: (same as `factorial()`)

```
1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
3628800
39916800
479001600
1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
3628800
39916800
479001600
```

Comment: I'd say `factorial2` is silly. Pointless to use `yield from` on an explicit generator expression.

Comment: @superbrain No it's not, using `yield from`, as a form of tail recursion is a valid use case, as you can see in this video as well https://youtu.be/5jwV3zxXc8E?t=553

Comment: Do you mean the `yield from sieve(...)` there? That's totally different, not a `yield from` on an explicit generator expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using a return value in the generator, which is what the `yield from` expression will eventually return:

```py
def factorial2(n):
    if n == 1:
        f = 1
    else:
        a = yield from factorial2(n - 1)
        f = n * a
    # Yielded by the generator
    yield f
    # Returned to `yield from`
    return f

for a in factorial2(12):
    print(a)
# 1
# 2
# 6
# 24
# 120
# 720
# 5040
# 40320
# 362880
# 3628800
# 39916800
# 479001600
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer. By looking at it, I think I was missing the return statements, which transferred the previous results, to the yield from statements.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the yield statements return the results back to the caller, whereas the return statements ensure that the results are being forwarded internally back to the factorial function itself, right?

Comment: @solid.py Yes, `yield f` is responsible for getting `f` out of the stack call up back to the `for` loop, whereas `return f` is responsible for getting `f` to the immediately previous call. You can get the last `return`ed value from outside `factorial2` if you capture the `StopIteration` exception at the end of the generator. E.g. `try: a = factorial2(4); while True: next(a); except StopIteration as e: print(e.value)` will print the `24` returned by the last `return f`.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have for `factorial2` is equivalent to:

```
# wrong code, do not use
def factorial2(n):
    if n == 1:
        yield 1
    else:
        for i in factorial2(n - 1):
            yield i * n
```

I hope you can see why that doesn't work.

Instead, you might try to tackle this problem from the other side, using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count).

```
from itertools import count

def factorial3(n):
    yield 1
    if n > 1:
        yield from (u * i for u, i in zip(factorial3(n - 1), count(2)))
```

Comment: Okay, so we can see `factorial2(1)` yields exactly once. `factorial2(2)` yields exactly as many times as `factorial2(1)` yields (because of the `for` loop), and in general `factorial2(n)` yields as many times as `factorial2(n - 1)` does if `n > 1`. This means that it will always yield exactly once.